# Is there a way to Insert a Table from external pdf similar to inserting external pdf as figure?

Tags: org-export, latex, table

We can easily insert figures from external PDF, but how do I insert a table the same way?

For example: I have a table in `.tex` file in a `standalone` class as it is easier to generate it from an external program. And I have the compiled PDF from it.

What I want is basically this in LaTeX/PDF export:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{tab:dams}Dams in the Basin}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{./dams.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

If I do `[[./dams.pdf]]` then it automatically becomes an image, and the `#+caption:` will be `Figure 1`. Is there any way I can tell org mode that this is supposed to be inserted as a table?

I found a workaround using `#+begin_table` but it doesn't get recognized as `table` for the caption to be on top with the variable `org-latex-caption-above` variable.

But with:

```
#+name: tab:dams
#+caption: Dams in the Basin
#+begin_table
[[./dams.pdf]]
#+end_table
```

OR with

```
#+name: tab:dams
#+caption: Dams in the Basin
#+ATTR_LATEX: :float table
[[./dams.pdf]]
```

And variable `setq org-latex-caption-above` as `(table)` (default), I get:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{./dams.pdf}
\end{center}
\caption{\label{tab:dams}Dams in the Basin}
\end{table}
```

I don't want all the captions including figures to be on top, so if there is a way to make this form recognized as table and have the caption on top would work. Or another way where I can include something as table using org syntax would work too.

I do not want to put LaTeX code for the whole table syntax in org document as I'd like to have references to that table in the text and have the link clickable to open the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the way to make the workaround work for now.

Since the `#+begin_table` is recognized as `special-block` instead of `table` I can add that to the `org-latex-caption-above` variable.

```
 (setq org-latex-caption-above '(table special-block))
```

It'll work for my usecase, but if you have other special blocks that you don't want the caption to be on the top, then it will be problematic.

It'd still be a good idea to know if there is a way to make it recognized as a table when inserted with link to a PDF/PNG file.